# How to decrement an item Quantity from an array in java if there are multiple classes?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, getter-setter

Why does when a user purchase an item, the quantity of the item is not deducting or updating and still it is the same? what should i do to correct the implementation of this?

```
    public RegularVendingMachine createRegVM() {
        RegularVendingMachine vendingMachine = new RegularVendingMachine();

        int numSlots = readValidInteger(1, 8, "\nEnter no. of slot items (MAX: 8): ");
        int itemCount = readValidInteger(1, 10, "Enter no. of items (MAX: 10): ");
        System.out.println("\nItem Count: " + itemCount);
        vendingMachine.setItemCount(itemCount);

        for (int i = 0; i < numSlots; i++) {
            System.out.println("===================================");
            System.out.println("Enter details for Item " + (i + 1) + ":");
            System.out.println("===================================");
            String itemName = readString("Name of item: ");
            double price = readValidDouble(0, Double.MAX_VALUE, "Enter a price for the item: ");
            int calories = readValidInteger(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE, "Enter no. of calories of the item: ");

            Item item = new Item();
            item.setItemName(itemName);
            item.setItemPrice(price);
            item.setItemCalories(calories);
            vendingMachine.addItem(String.valueOf(i + 1), item);

            System.out.println("Item " + (i + 1) + " Detials:");
            System.out.println("Name: " + item.getItemName());
            System.out.println("Price: " + item.getItemPrice());
            System.out.println("Calories: " + item.getItemCalories());
        }

        System.out.println("Your Regular Vending Machine is created successfully!");
        System.out.println("Enjoy your goodies...");
        return vendingMachine;
    } 
private void displayAvailableItems() {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Available Items:");
        Map<String, Item> inventory = getInventory();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Item> entry : inventory.entrySet()) {
            String slot = entry.getKey();
            Item item = entry.getValue();            
            System.out.println("Slot " + slot + " - " + item.getItemName() + " - Php " + item.getItemPrice() + " - Quantity: " + itemCount);
        }
    }

    public void purchaseItem() {
        System.out.println("");
    public void purchaseItem() {
    System.out.println();
    displayAvailableItems();
    System.out.println();
    String slot = readValidString("Enter the slot of the item you want to purchase: ");
    double amount = readValidDouble(0, Double.MAX_VALUE, "Enter the amount of money: ");

    Item item = getItem(slot);
    if (item != null) {
        if (item.isAvailable()) {
            if (amount >= item.getItemPrice()) {
                double change = amount - item.getItemPrice();
                System.out.println("\nYou purchased: " + item.getItemName());
                System.out.println("Change: Php" + change);
                item.decrementItemQuantity(); // Decrement the item quantity by 1
                item.incrementUnitsSold(); // Increment units sold count
                salesSum += item.getItemPrice(); // Update the sales sum
                System.out.println("Inventory updated successfully!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Insufficient funds. Please insert more money.");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Item is out of stock.");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid slot. Please try again.");
    }
}

    public void updateInventory(String itemName) {
        for (Slot slot : slots) {
            ArrayList<Item> itemSlot = slot.getItemSlot();
            for (Item item : itemSlot) {
                if (item.getItemName().equals(itemName)) {
                    item.setItemQuantity(item.getItemQuantity() + 1);
                    System.out.println("Inventory updated for item: " + itemName);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

here is the 2nd class (Item):

```
public class Item {
    private String itemName;         // The name of the item
    private double itemPrice;        // The price of the item
    private int itemCalories;        // The calories of the item
    private int itemQuantity;        // The quantity of the item
    private boolean itemAvailability;    // The availability of the item
    private int unitsSold;           // The number of units sold for the item

    public Item() {
        this.itemName = "Empty";
        this.itemPrice = -1;
        this.itemCalories = -1;
        this.itemQuantity = -1;
        this.itemAvailability = false;
    }

    public Item(String itemName, int itemPrice, int itemCalories, int itemQuantity, boolean itemAvailability) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
        this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
        this.itemCalories = itemCalories;
        this.itemQuantity = itemQuantity;
        this.itemAvailability = itemAvailability;
    }

    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }

    public double getItemPrice() {
        return itemPrice;

    public int getItemCalories() {
        return itemCalories;
    }

    public int getItemQuantity() {
        return itemQuantity;
    }

    public boolean getItemAvailability() {
        return itemAvailability;
    }

    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }

    public void setItemPrice(double itemPrice) {
        this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
    }

    public void setItemCalories(int itemCalories) {
        this.itemCalories = itemCalories;
    }

    public void setItemQuantity(int itemQuantity) {
        this.itemQuantity = itemQuantity;
    }

    public void setItemAvailability(boolean itemAvailability) {
        this.itemAvailability = itemAvailability;
    }

    public boolean isAvailable() {
        return itemQuantity > 0;
    }

    public void itemRestock(int capacity) {
        if (itemQuantity < capacity) {
            int addedItems = capacity - itemQuantity;
            System.out.println("\nRestocking " + addedItems + " " + itemName + "(s)...");
            itemQuantity = capacity;
            System.out.println("Restocking complete! The vending machine now has " + itemQuantity + " " + itemName + "(s).");
        } else {
            System.out.println("\nNo restocking needed! The vending machine already has the maximum capacity of " + itemQuantity + " " + itemName + "(s).");
        }
    }

    public double calculateTotalPrice(int quantity) {
        return itemPrice * quantity;
    }

    public int getUnitsSold() {
        return unitsSold;
    }

    public void incrementUnitsSold() {
        unitsSold++;
    }
}
```

i tried adding another method in item, which decreases the quantity by 1 but  still it does not work that the quantity should be reduced

```
public void decrementItemQuantity() {
        if (itemQuantity > 0) {
            itemQuantity--;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think I might be able to help you: But I'm a bit confused about what you exactly want to do. The decrementItemQuantity function is correct and should be placed in the ItemClass. Now for every Item you possess there should be an Object of the Item Class. Where do you define these?

Comment: in another class i have method where i get the object of the item class

Comment: What is `getItem(slot)` ? What is `slot`at all ? No code shows how it is created nor filled (with items, I guess). I guess you don't show all significant code.

Comment: How do you do this? Probably you got something wrong when you create the Objects. But as @PeterMmm said: the significant code is missing